# How to set the color and font style of placeholder text

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I want to set the color to the placeholder, change the font style to bold, and increase the size.

How can I achieve this? Should I give style to the placeholder, or is there any other way can I achieve this? I want to set the color and change font style to work in all browsers for select size in the below result.

```html
<!doctype html>



<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }


.k-dropdown-wrap{
  border-width: 5px !important;
  border-color: #D8D3D3 !important;
}

}



</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



    <div id="example" role="application">
        <div id="tshirt-view" class="demo-section k-content">

        
        <select id="size" placeholder="Select City..." style="width: 300px;" >
          <option />
          <option />Newyork
          <option />Hyderabad
          <option />Bangalore
          <option />Kolkata
          <option />Delhi
        </select>


    </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // create ComboBox from input HTML element

                // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                $("#size").kendoComboBox();


                var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");



            });


        </script>
    </div></!doctype>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the following code **for cross-browser support**:

For **Google Chrome**:

```css
.element::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For **Mozilla Firefox**:

```css
.element::-moz-placeholder {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For **Internet Explorer**:

```css
.element:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For **Opera**:

```css
.element:-o-input-placeholder {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: How to add bold? @Angel Politis

Comment: @overflowstack9 put **`font-weight: bold`**. I'll edit to show you.

Comment: Glad I  could help you @overflowstack9

Comment: can i put all css codes in my code i mean to add the style i mean if i put all codes only it work for all browsers ..?

Comment: You have to put all of them @overflowstack9 if you want cross-browser support.

Comment: oh ok wow great sense of all css codes for all browsers good really appreciable @angel politis

Answer (score 8):

you can find this and more css tricks here

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
   font-weight: 800;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
   font-weight: 800;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
   font-weight: 800;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
   font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>



<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }


.k-dropdown-wrap{
  border-width: 5px !important;
  border-color: #D8D3D3 !important;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
}



</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



    <div id="example" role="application">
        <div id="tshirt-view" class="demo-section k-content">

        <h4 style="margin-bottom: .5em;">Select City</h4>
        <select id="size" placeholder="Select City..." style="width: 300px;" >
          <option />
          <option />Newyork
          <option />Hyderabad
          <option />Bangalore
          <option />Kolkata
          <option />Delhi
        </select>


    </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // create ComboBox from input HTML element

                // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                $("#size").kendoComboBox();


                var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");



            });


        </script>
    </div></!doctype>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [placeholder](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/) pseudo element
And `font-weight` to make it bolder

```html
<!doctype html>



<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }


.k-dropdown-wrap{
  border-width: 5px !important;
  border-color: #D8D3D3 !important;
}
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        font-weight: 800; 
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder {
        font-weight: 800; 
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
        font-weight: 800; 
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        font-weight: 800; 
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}



</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



    <div id="example" role="application">
        <div id="tshirt-view" class="demo-section k-content">

        <h4 style="margin-bottom: .5em;">Select City</h4>
        <select id="size" placeholder="Select City..." style="width: 300px;" >
          <option />
          <option />Newyork
          <option />Hyderabad
          <option />Bangalore
          <option />Kolkata
          <option />Delhi
        </select>


    </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // create ComboBox from input HTML element

                // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                $("#size").kendoComboBox();


                var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");



            });


        </script>
    </div></!doctype>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the for customizing placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #909;
    font-size:12px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #909;
   font-size:12px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #909;
   font-size:12px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #909;
   font-size:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, just the `font-weight: normal;` worked like

```
.class {
font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for all browser

```
input::placeholder {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```