# scss file set place holder text to bold

Tags: css, angular, html

I have an angular front end in which i have a form with textarea:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <textarea class="left-aligned" formcontrolname="x1" matInput placeholder="some text"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

i also have a scss file for that component with:

```
mat-form-field{
margin-left:20px;
}
```

I have tried using selecotors by class

```
.s {
mat-palceholder:{
 font-weight: bold;
}
}
```

but that didnt work...

How do i make the placeholder text BOLD?
How do i make part of the placeholder text BOLD?

i also did:
added class name

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <textarea class="left-aligned x1" formcontrolname="x1" matInput placeholder="some text"/>
    </mat-form-field>
```

added to the scss file

```
.x1::placeholder{
color: green;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

but that didnt work..

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the color and font style of placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487394/how-to-set-the-color-and-font-style-of-placeholder-text)

Comment: Have you set the ViewEncapsulation to "None" in the component?

Answer (score 0):

This how you can change the placeholder style

```
::placeholder { // *::placeholder 
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold
}

.class-name::placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold
}

input::placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold
}
```

as far I know you can't change some of the text to bold and other is not the style apply to all placeholder text

in case of angular material

style.css

```
mat-form-field span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  color:red !important;
}


mat-form-field.mat-focused span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  color:blue !important;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdkq6y)

Comment: @user1997656 I have update the answer and include onl;ine demo

Answer (score 0):

Use the `::placeholder` selector along with the input class.

```
.left-aligned::placeholder { // Your Css code }
```

More reading: [Placeholders](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

please use `<textarea></textarea>` like this... without any space beetween tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `encapsulation` as below:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Maybe your styles are not working because `mat-form-field` is a different component and your `textarea` is inside that component.

For more information, please check [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-components/view_encapsulation.html)